# Magento 2 (Rest api): Get all products based on update_at criteria

Tags: magento2, rest-api

How to get the products from magento 2 using REST API based on the updated_at criteria, so I can able to get products created/updated on particular date. how to achieve this task. please help me.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you can use search criteria for the same, for updated_at param

Comment: @Wisam answer seems to correct, However your error is related to OAuth. Please see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/authentication/oauth-errors.html

Comment: Are you sending token with request ?

Comment: without filter criteria i'm able to get response. but when I include the filter criteria it says me invalid signature. @Pawan

Comment: i'm sending the token with request @Pawan

Comment: if any answer solves your concern then please mark as right for future readers, or post your own solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

> GET /V1/products?&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2018-09-07&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gteq

This endpoint will give you all products that being updated after **2018-09-07** it is working for me, I hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I have tried your answer in my apex controller, in the response I'm getting {"message":"Invalid signature"}. without filter criteria getting all the products in the response. can you guide me. where I have made mistake

Answer (score 1):

**catalogProductRepositoryV1**

> you can use **search Criteria**

```
    http://<magento_host>/rest/V1/products/?
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2018-09-17 00:00:00&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]‌​=eq
```

> method type : **GET**

**The system creates an array, as shown in the following pseudo-code.**

```
searchCriteria => [
  'filterGroups' => [
    0 => [
      'filters' => [
         0 => [
           'field' => 'updated_at',
           'value' => '2018-09-17 00:00:00',
           'condition_type' => 'eq'
         ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I have tried your answer in my apex controller, in the response I'm getting {"message":"Invalid signature"}. without filter criteria i'm getting all the products in the response

Comment: Does that return all a configurable products simple products if the configurable product or simple product has changed?  Or would be only get the entity that has changed?