# Magento2: REST API GET all Orders

Tags: magento2, rest-api

How to GET all orders from magento 2 through Rest API. what is the endpoint url to retrieve all order irrespective of customers.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: http://host/demostore/rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria=0.  I got response am i correct.

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There a good tutorial about Magento 2 API [Here](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-api/)

On the basis of above tutorial you can get all order by:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "1");

$userData = array("username" => "Admin_username", "password" => "Admin_password");
$ch = curl_init("http://127.0.0.1/mago/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

echo $token = curl_exec($ch);

$ch = curl_init("http://127.0.0.1/mago/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria=all");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

**Note:** `searchCriteria=all` and `searchCriteria=0` both are giving same results

Comment: thanks Pawan... I have one more doubt. when I try to use filter in products query I'm getting invalid signature in response. without filter I get success response.

Comment: are you asking about https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241052 ? I will update answer to that question soon

Comment: If above answer helped/worked, You can accept and upvote it :)

Comment: yes pawan. in postman its working. when it comes salesforce apex controller rest api call out... it gives me error....  magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241052

Comment: I am checking other question.

Comment: How to fetch order in desc order i.e latest ones

Comment: @SairajGadekar, you can try `index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria=all&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC`