# Magento 2 REST get all Orders with admin token. CustomerID?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5-p1

When I try to get all orders of my store...

Similar to this one: [Magento2: REST API GET all Orders](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241793/magento2-rest-api-get-all-orders)

I receive this message:

```
message: Does not exist the entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "customerId",
        "fieldValue": null
    }
}
```

How I get all orders??

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this REST API URL.

> http://yourdomain.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria=all

Answer (score 0):

Yes...this is the URL that I Call... but I receive the message:

{
"message": "No existe la entidad con %fieldName = %fieldValue",
"parameters": {
"fieldName": "customerId",
"fieldValue": null
}
}